# Iterating through a list and searching for each element in another list in c++

Tags: c++, list, search, iterator, element

I have created a list of 4 elements called "worklist." I have another list called "choicelist" which has around 40 elements in it. I want to check if any of the elements in "worklist" are present in "choicelist".

I understand that I'd use "std::find" from  to search, but how would I go about checking for each element IN ORDER from "worklist" in "choicelist"?

Baring in mind that once an element from "worklist" HAS been found in "choicelist" I want the search process to end (and preferably some kind of notification about which element in "worklist" was the first one to match).

Comment: This is a rudimentary way of doing things, but like you said, for each element in `worklist`, perform a `std::find` in `choicelist` for that element. If you get something back (not the end iterator), then it's there. Otherwise, its not.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate over elements of first list      and check is it there in second list using find function. if it finds the searching element ,  print it and break the loop.

```
std::list<int> worklist;
std::list<int> choicelist;
//This loop only works in C++11 and above, 
//in case of C++98, you need to use iterators to iterate over list
for( auto &x : worklist) 
{
        //auto is also a feature of C++11 and above
        auto y = std::find (std::begin(choicelist),
                            std::end(choicelist), x);

        if( y != choicelist.end())
        {
            std::cout<< *y<<"\n";
            break;
        }
 }
```

if you just need to find first element of first container  in second container,

```
auto y= std::find_first_of(std:begin(choicelist), std::end(choicelist),
                           std::begin(worklist), std::end(worklist));
if( y != choicelist.end())
{
                std::cout<< *y<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: It is worth noticing that this will only work in C++11 and above :)

Comment: @Lectral I included it as a comment

Comment: So say that I had the values "2,3,4,5" in worklist and the values "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" in choicelist, I am looking for the cout to ONLY be "2". Would this code achieve this?

Comment: @Matthew If that is the case you don't need loop, you can just use std::find_first_of in place of std::find . I will update code